# How to convert a list of GPS coordinates to IS0 alpha 3 country codes using the GeoNames package in R?

Tags: r, coordinates, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, geonames

I have a large dataframe of global ports with assigned latitude and longitude coordinates.
I want to convert the list of coordinates into their equivalent IS0 alpha 3 country codes, using GeoNames package in R.

Here is an example of the ports dataframe:

**ports.df**

```
                    ports                   lat                   long

            Port of Barcadera              12.479722            -69.99234

            Port of Oranjestad             12.520000            -70.03881

            Port of San Nicolas            12.430000            -69.91000

            Port of Ambriz                 -7.833056             13.09376

            Port of Cabinda                -5.550000             12.19022

            Port of Lobito                -12.330000             13.56000
```

Instead of reverse geo-coding (coordinates ->  address)
I want to  reverse geo-code for country codes (coordinates -> ISO alpha 3 country codes)

An an example of what I want to achieve is shown below:
(Convert the coordinates into ISO alpha country code, and create an additional column 'ISO alpha 3')

**ports_ISO3<-cbind(ports.df,ISO alpha)**

```
                ports              lat                long         ISO alpha 3

          Port of Barcadera       12.479722           -69.99234           ABU       

          Port of Oranjestad      12.520000           -70.03881           ABU

          Port of San Nicolas     12.430000           -69.91000           ABU

          Port of Ambriz          -7.833056            13.09376           AGO

          Port of Cabinda         -5.550000            12.19022           AGO

          Port of Lobito         -12.330000            13.56000           AGO
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Try to use the tags sp and sf to get more views... Also this might be better for Geographic Information System

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work.

First we need to load some R packages

```r
library(geonames)
library(ISOcodes)
library(purrr)
options(width = 120)
```

Then we load the data

```r
my_ports <- data.frame(
  ports = c(
    "Port of Barcadera", "Port of Oranjestad", "Port of San Nicolas", "Port of Ambriz"
  ), 
  lat = c(12.479722, 12.520000, 12.430000, -7.833056),
  lng = c(-69.99234, -70.03881, -69.91000, 13.09376)
)
```

Now we can geocode the country code. The `map2_dfr` function is exported from the R package `purrr`. `radius = 10` is used to set a 10km radius threshold between the point and the closet country. You may want to change that value.

```r
my_ports_countrycode <- map2_dfr(
  my_ports[["lat"]], 
  my_ports[["lng"]], 
  .f = GNcountryCode, 
  radius = 10
)
my_ports_countrycode
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   languages       distance countryCode countryName       
#>   <chr>           <chr>    <chr>       <chr>             
#> 1 nl-AW,pap,es,en 0.08644  AW          Aruba             
#> 2 nl-AW,pap,es,en 0        AW          Aruba             
#> 3 nl-AW,pap,es,en 0.13839  AW          Aruba             
#> 4 pt-AO           2.22605  AO          Republic of Angola
```

Now I can merge the original data with the country codes

```r
my_ports <- cbind(my_ports, my_ports_countrycode)
my_ports
#>                 ports       lat       lng       languages distance countryCode        countryName
#> 1   Port of Barcadera 12.479722 -69.99234 nl-AW,pap,es,en  0.08644          AW              Aruba
#> 2  Port of Oranjestad 12.520000 -70.03881 nl-AW,pap,es,en        0          AW              Aruba
#> 3 Port of San Nicolas 12.430000 -69.91000 nl-AW,pap,es,en  0.13839          AW              Aruba
#> 4      Port of Ambriz -7.833056  13.09376           pt-AO  2.22605          AO Republic of Angola
```

If you want to add the iso_alpha3_code you can use a left join with the full table of ISO codes:

```r
merge(my_ports, ISO_3166_1, by.x = "countryCode", by.y = "Alpha_2", sort = FALSE)
#>   countryCode               ports       lat       lng       languages distance        countryName Alpha_3 Numeric
#> 1          AW   Port of Barcadera 12.479722 -69.99234 nl-AW,pap,es,en  0.08644              Aruba     ABW     533
#> 2          AW  Port of Oranjestad 12.520000 -70.03881 nl-AW,pap,es,en        0              Aruba     ABW     533
#> 3          AW Port of San Nicolas 12.430000 -69.91000 nl-AW,pap,es,en  0.13839              Aruba     ABW     533
#> 4          AO      Port of Ambriz -7.833056  13.09376           pt-AO  2.22605 Republic of Angola     AGO     024
#>     Name      Official_name Common_name
#> 1  Aruba               <NA>        <NA>
#> 2  Aruba               <NA>        <NA>
#> 3  Aruba               <NA>        <NA>
#> 4 Angola Republic of Angola        <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! That piece of code works perfectly for the first 6 locations of my dataframe (the locations shown above). However, when I try to run this code for the entire dataframe (~2000 locations), an error displays:  **Error in getJson("countryCode", list(lat = lat, lng = lng, radius = radius,  : 
  error code 15 from server: no country code found**.      I think this is because some of the GPS locations do not match with a country code, so produces an error. Is there anyway of modifying the code so that it ignores any N/A results and continue running the results?

Comment: Can you try running the code increasing the max radius? Like 20 or 30

Comment: I tried changing the radius to 30, which seemed to work but then another error came up saying I've reached my hourly limit of 1,000 credits. GeoNames software only allows up to 1000 credits without premium. I have 1917 entries, so couldn't finish the conversion. Other than paying for GeoNames premium (which is too expensive), is there another way around this problem? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can split your data in 2, geocode the first part, save the result, wait 1 hour, and geocode the second part.